# Dynamic hide/unhide tab regarding a form field value in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a template that renders three forms in tabs.

The third form is hidden and I want to  dynamically in if a value in a field (having choices via drop down) of the second form is selected.

When I select the option **b-option** on the second form, I want to unhide the third tab.

Any ideas?

**input.html (template)**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="tab-pane">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Demographics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Diagnosis</a>
            </li>
            <li class="hide">
                <a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">A_b_sickle</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
                <div class="container"> {%crispy frm%}</div>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">
                <div class="container">{%crispy frm_d%}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
                <div class="container"> {%crispy frm_a_b_s%}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def input(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_demographics = DemographicForm(request.POST, prefix="demo")
        my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diag')
        my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm(request.POST,prefix='a_b_s')

        if my_demographics.is_valid() and my_diagnosis.is_valid() and my_a_b_sickle.is_valid:
            my_demographics_object = my_demographics.save()
            my_diagnosis_object = my_diagnosis.save(commit=False)
            my_diagnosis_object.patient = my_demographics_object
            my_diagnosis_object.save()

            my_a_b_sickle_object = my_a_b_sickle.save(commit=False)
            my_a_b_sickle_object.patient = my_demographics_object

            my_a_b_sickle_object.save()
    else:
        my_demographics = DemographicForm(prefix='demo')
        my_diagnosis = DiagnosisForm(prefix='diag')
        my_a_b_sickle= A_b_sickle_thalForm(prefix='a_b_s')

    return render_to_response('input.html', {'frm':my_demographics, 'frm_d': my_diagnosis, 'frm_a_b_s': my_a_b_sickle}, context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
    age_of_diagnosis = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    diagnosis_option_value = (
        ('a-option', 'a-option'),
        ('b-option', 'b-option'),
    )
    diagnosis_option = models.CharField( max_length=45,choices=diagnosis_option_value, default=diagnosis_option_value[0][0])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

**Edit: template code after rendering**

```
<div id="div_id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="form-group"><label for="id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="control-label  requiredField">
    Diagnosis option<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label><div class="controls "><select class="select form-control" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option" name="diag-diagnosis_option"><option value="a-option" selected="selected">a-option</option><option value="b-option">b-option</option>select></div></div>
```

**Edited: my solution**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id_diag-diagnosis_option').change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val()
                if (value === 'b-option'){
                    $('#mytab a[href="#3"]').parent().removeClass("hide");
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in Javascript/jQuery:

```
// For each check box bind
$("#id_diag-diagnosis_option").change(function(){
    // Get the value of the option
    var value = $(this).val()

    // Check the value
    if (value === "b-option"){
        // Show the tab
        $('#myTab a').tab('show');
    }

})
```

Don't forget to change the `tab_id` with the right `myTab a` and the correct API call to show the tab!

Comment: Regarding `select_id`, the field is in `frm_d`. How will I configure it?

Comment: I posted to my question the template code after rendering. Can you provide me more precise example?

Comment: See the update above ! I still need the tabs rendering to update the code

Comment: Thank you. This the `tab_id` value `<div class="tab-pane" id="3">` right? So my code would be like `$("#3").show()`?

Comment: Also, I must unhide the tab without pushing the submit button!

Comment: Test it, I can't tell you more than this until I see the full code, but you can test it yourself, you should do that !

Comment: It does not working :( I tested it. In `input.html` you can see my tabs. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you include the jQuery plug-in for the navs/tabs ?!

Comment: If you mean to include the corresponding header scripts, yes.

Comment: Dude this is an example with your HTML and i can switch tabs as I want, you need to do it your self ! use this as a guide and do the rest ! http://jsfiddle.net/xedycpu3/

Comment: I can switch the two tabs. I need to show the third one. For example can you modify the code to hide tab 1 when I click on tab 2?

Comment: What do I must do to see the updated version? If I open the link once again, I see the previous code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63714/discussion-between-e-nouri-and-zinon).