# Click in a dropdown option and show an specific field in Django

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement

I have the following situation, I have this model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    DEVELOPER = 1
    MARKETER = 2
    ACADEMIC = 3
    INFLUENCER = 4
    COMMUNITY_MEMBER = 5

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (DEVELOPER, 'Developer'),
        (MARKETER, 'Marketer'),
        (ACADEMIC, 'Academic'),
        (INFLUENCER, 'Influencer'),
        (COMMUNITY_MEMBER, 'Community Member'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    account_type = models.ForeignKey(AccountType, default=AccountType.FREE)
    role = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    github_profile = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_profile = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And now what I want to do is that if the user clicks in the dropwdown the `Developer` option, the github_profile should appear, otherwise it should keep hide.

Right now, looks like this, and the Github Link fields should be hide:

[image]

And this is my html:

```
  <div class="form-group select-wrapper">
    <label for="role">What best describes you?</label>
    <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Choose an option</option>
      {% for index, value in roles_form.fields.roles.choices %}
          <option value="{{ index }}">{{ value }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  <span class="role-error hidden" style="color: red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="github_profile">GitHub Profile (optional)</label>
      <input type="url" class="form-control" name="github_profile" id="github_profile" placeholder="https://github.com/your-profile">
      <span class="github_profile-error hidden" style="color: red"></span>
  </div>
```

I know this is a conditional thing, however I'm brand new in Django and I'm not pretty sure how to achieve it.

**EDIT:**

I did the following function:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

          var value = $(this).val();
          if (value == 1) {
             $('#github_link').show();
          } else if (value != 1) {
             $('#github_link').hide();
          }
  })
```

It works but I got the following feedback: Here you have hardcoded the value "1", but if the positioning on this list changes, then this behavior will break. Instead, you should reference the variable {{ model.profile.DEVELOPER }} which will yield the current value of the variable DEVELOPER, even if it changes.

Comment: where do you want to show that? in django admin? or in your own form template?

Comment: @Lemayzeur  I edited the question, so it is currently in my html template, but the Github Link should be hidden.

Comment: you can do this with js

Comment: @Lemayzeur Just adding the script tag at the end of the html template right?

Comment: Correct, add an event listener to your `select` tag to detect when `developer` is chosen

Comment: It's hard to understand, can you edit your question with what you've tried. Thank you

Comment: Fixed @Lemayzeur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172710/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-enrique-vargas).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve that is use Javascript. For example with jQuery like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589859/5698557